# return complicated class from c# to jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, list, class

I have a c# class (myClass) that consist of properties and Listof otherClass. After setting myClass properties and adding items to the otherClass List I return the class (myClass) to jQuery with the following command -

```
context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myClass));
```

In my jquery success function I parseJSON with the following command -

```
var a = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Problem is I get the myClass object without the otherClass List...

How can I send back to jQuery the the myClass class including the List of otherClass ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolving it with `JavaScriptSerializer` would be a pain. Use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

```
context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass));
```

Answer (score -1):

Changing the List of otherClass from **private** to **public** solve the issue.

Thanks